# Scala matching arrays 2d

Tags: arrays, scala, match, 2d

I have 2d Array which is declared like that `init_ : Array[Array[Int]]`

In this 2d array, i can only have "1","2" or "3". 
I'm looking to print something different when i iterate on these elements, something like that :

```
  override def toString = {  
    val c = init.map(_.clone);  

    c match{
      case 1 => ret = "one"
      case 2 => ret = "two"
      case 3 => ret = "three"
    }
    ret
  }
```

I'm beginning in Scala so please, be indulgent

```
Here is my 2d arrays : 

val tab = $(
      $(1, 2, 3, 
      $(1, 2, 3, 
      $(1, 2, 3)
```

I've imported things like that : `import scala.{Array => $};`

Thanks

Comment: can you post a sample example of your 2D array?

Comment: Yes, done @Vamsi

Comment: do you just want to check the elements in the 2D array are 1,2,3 or not?

Comment: Yes i want to print something different for each case, if it's 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example to iterate a two 2D array and do pattern matching

```
import scala.{Array => $}

      val tab = $(
        $(1, 2, 1),
        $(1, 2, 2),
        $(3, 2, 3),
        $(4, 2, 4))


      val rowsSize = tab.length
      val columnsSize = tab(0).length

      for (i <- 0 to rowsSize - 1; j <- 0 to columnsSize - 1) {
        tab(i)(j) match {
          case 1 => println("one")
          case 2 => println("two")
          case 3 => println("three")
          case x => println(x)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me